# Show that $L(v) = \int_{\Gamma} gv ds$ is a continuous operator

Tags: multivariable-calculus, finite-element-method, greens-theorem

This is problem 2.4 from "Numerical Solution of Partial Differential Equations by the Finite Element Method" by Claes Johnson.

Let $\Omega$ be a square with boundary $\Gamma$. Show that there is a constant C such that
$$\left(\int_\Gamma v^2 ds\right)^{1/2}\le C||v||_{H^1(\Omega)}, \forall v\in H^1(\Omega)$$
Then use that result to show that
$$L(v)=\int_\Gamma gv ds$$
is continuous if $g\in L^2(\Gamma)$.

**Idea:** I think I need to use Green's theorem, and the fact that were are specifically working with a square. However, I don't know how to turn that into an actual mathematical argument.

Comment: I've been in Finite Element applications for quite some (40) years, and still don't see much relevance in the theory building concerning this area of interest. But that's not your fault, obviously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first inequality is indeed Trace theorem (see Evans PDE page 272). The idea is as follows:
    Suppose $\Omega=[0,1]\times[0,1]$, and $\Gamma = \Gamma_1\cup \Gamma_2\cup \Gamma_3\cup \Gamma_4$, where
    \begin{align*}
  \Gamma_1&=[0,1]\times \left\{ 0 \right\};\\
  \Gamma_2&=[0,1]\times \left\{ 1 \right\};\\
  \Gamma_3& = \left\{ 0 \right\}\times[0,1];\\
  \Gamma_4& = \left\{ 1 \right\}\times[0,1].
 \end{align*}
    Then select a cut off function $\zeta\in C^{\infty}(\Omega)$ s.t. $\zeta=1$ on $\Gamma_1$ and $\zeta=0$ on $\Gamma_2$. 
    \begin{align*}
  \int_{\Gamma_1}v^2ds &= -\int_{\Omega}(\zeta v^2)_{x_2}dx_1dx_2\\
  & =-\int_{\Omega}\zeta_{x_2}v^2+\zeta vv_{x_2}dx_1dx_2\\
  & \leq C\int_{\Omega}|v|^2+|Dv|^2dx_1dx_2
 \end{align*}
    where we used Young's inequality. In a similar way, one can show that this inequality holds for $\Gamma_2$, $\Gamma_3$ and $\Gamma_4$. In all, 
    \begin{equation}
  \left( \int_{\Gamma}v^2ds \right)^{\frac{1}{2}}\leq C\|v\|_{H^{1}(\Omega)}.
 \end{equation}
    For the second part, since $L$ is a linear funciotnal over $H^{1}(\Omega)$, therefore it is continuous if and only if it is bounded, that is
    \begin{equation}
  L(v)=\int_{\Gamma}^{}gvds\leq \|g\|_{L^2(\Gamma)}\|v\|_{L^2(\Gamma)}\leq C\|v\|_{H^1(\Omega)}.
 \end{equation}